# Proof $ df(x,\,y) = {\partial f \over \partial x} dx + { \partial f \over \partial y } dy $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Proof differential of multivariable function $$ df(x,\,y) = {\partial f \over \partial x} dx + { \partial f \over \partial y } dy $$

Comment: See [here](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/summer2011/handouts/33-chainrule.pdf).

Comment: [How To Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 4):

You are in a 2 dimensional manifold. By definition, $\mathrm d f$ is a $1-$form, and thus written (uniquely) as $$\mathrm d f=a\,\mathrm d x+b\,\mathrm d y.$$

Now, by definition $$\mathrm df(\partial _x):=\partial _xf,$$
and $$\mathrm d f(\partial _y):=\partial _yf.$$
This yield $a=\partial _xf$ and $b=\partial _yf$.

Comment: Hello @surb Is it possible to get this proof using limit of slope formula (first principle) of differentiation.

Comment: @123: Not really. All the problem is the meaning of $\mathrm df:=d_{(x,y)}f$ which is defined as the linear approximation at $(x,y)$. So, this is rather an algebraic fact than an analysis fact

Comment: But @J.K attachment has short proof of this. Is there any detailed.

Comment: @123: who do you mean by J.K ? You mean J.G ? I don't think that it's really an analytic proof.